# How to get LinkedIn Profile information other then the default information Android

Tags: android, integration, linkedin-api, access-token

I am getting the default information of user like Firstname and last name one URL(Site-standard Url), But i want to access the User_id and smilar info . I follow "https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api" and implement like following code.
Please Help me out. I hit and try many things but could not get success.

```
public class LinkedInTestActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    public static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";`enter code here`
    LinkedInAccessToken accessToken;
    public static final String APP_NAME = "LITest";
    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME = "x-oauthflow-linkedin";
    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST = "callback";
    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME+ "://" + OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST;

    final LinkedInOAuthService oAuthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET);
    final LinkedInApiClientFactory factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
    LinkedInRequestToken liToken;
    LinkedInApiClient client;

    TextView tv = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        liToken = oAuthService.getOAuthRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
        Log.e("liToken.getAuthorizationUrl()",""+liToken.getAuthorizationUrl());
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(liToken.getAuthorizationUrl()));
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        String verifier = intent.getData().getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
        Log.e("Verifier-------->",""+verifier);
        Log.e("liToken-------->",""+liToken);
        accessToken = oAuthService.getOAuthAccessToken(liToken, verifier);
        Log.e("accessToken-------->",""+accessToken.getToken());
        client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);
        client.postNetworkUpdate("LinkedIn Android app test");
        //      Person p = client.getProfileByUrl("http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~", ProfileType.STANDARD);

        Person p =client.getProfileForCurrentUser();
        p.getDateOfBirth();
        p.getApiStandardProfileRequest();
        p.getSiteStandardProfileRequest().getUrl();
        p.getHeadline();
        tv.setText(p.getLastName() + ", " + p.getFirstName()+ " DOB "+ p.getDateOfBirth());

        if (accessToken == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("access token cannot be null.");
        }
        try {
            URL url = new URL(LinkedInApiUrls.GET_CONNECTIONS_FOR_CURRENT_USER);
            HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            final OAuthConsumer consumer = getOAuthConsumer();
            consumer.setTokenWithSecret(accessToken.getToken(), accessToken.getTokenSecret());
            consumer.sign(request);
            request.connect();

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,industry,headline,public-profile-url)");
            consumer.sign(post); // here need the consumer for sign in for post the share
            org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
            Log.e("response",""+response.getHeaders(verifier).toString());

    } 

    protected OAuthConsumer getOAuthConsumer() {
        DefaultOAuthConsumer consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER
_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
consumer.setMessageSigner(new HmacSha1MessageSigner());
consumer.setSigningStrategy(new AuthorizationHeaderSigningStrategy());
return consumer;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question has so much code. You should only have the relevant sections for your question. Dont put so much that it irritates the reader. Read the FAQ

Answer (score 6):

For getting more user detail information Person object should be used as below,

Please replace this,

```
Person p =client.getProfileForCurrentUser();
```

with,

```
Person profile = client.getProfileForCurrentUser(EnumSet.of(
                ProfileField.ID, ProfileField.FIRST_NAME,
                ProfileField.LAST_NAME, ProfileField.HEADLINE,
                ProfileField.INDUSTRY, ProfileField.PICTURE_URL,
                ProfileField.DATE_OF_BIRTH, ProfileField.LOCATION_NAME,
                ProfileField.MAIN_ADDRESS, ProfileField.LOCATION_COUNTRY));
```

And thus you can get more detailed info. using this profile object,

```
        System.out.println("PersonID : " + profile.getId());
        System.out.println("Name : " + profile.getFirstName() + " "
                + profile.getLastName());
        System.out.println("Headline : " + profile.getHeadline());
        System.out.println("Industry : " + profile.getIndustry());
        System.out.println("Picture : " + profile.getPictureUrl());
        DateOfBirth dateOfBirth = profile.getDateOfBirth();
        System.out.println("DateOfBirth : " + dateOfBirth.getDay() + "/"
                + dateOfBirth.getMonth() + "/" + dateOfBirth.getYear());
        System.out.println("MAin Address : " + profile.getMainAddress());
        Location location = profile.getLocation();
        System.out.println("Location:" + location.getName() + " - "
                + location.getCountry().getCode());
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit the url using this Method and it works for me:-

```
private OAuthConsumer getConsumer() {
        OAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
        consumer.setTokenWithSecret(accessToken.getToken(), accessToken.getTokenSecret());
        return consumer;
    }

}
```